# jquery cell selection starts make rowspan for further cells

Tags: jquery, html, css

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyjye/13/)

Firstly i am new to jquery.

i have to make one cell selection only `#tableAppointment tbody tr td:nth-child(2)`
and textbox value should go to next cell where selection starts.

I made functionality in my fiddle but the textbox value goes to all cells. I have to set the  textbox value to the first cell and other cell be rowspan(Means user see for all cell selection only one textbox value).For getting value in next cells i have taken span tag of html but i dont want span tag.

```
//ONE cell selection code
var active = false;

            $('#tableAppointment tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').mousedown(function (ev)
            {
                active = true;
                $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight"); // clear previous selection
                ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
                $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
                $(this).addClass("temp_selected");
            });

            $('#tableAppointment tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').mousemove(function (ev)
            {
                if (active)
                {
                    $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
                    $(this).addClass("temp_selected");
                }
                if ($('.temp_selected').length == 3)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if ($('.temp_selected').length > 3)
                {
                    alert("Time slot not more than 30 minutes.");
                    $(this).removeClass("csstdhighlight");
                    $(this).removeClass("temp_selected");
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $(document).mouseup(function (ev)
            {
                active = false;
                $('.temp_selected').removeClass('.temp_selected');

            });
```

Comment: So, basically you want to select one cell at a time, without the cell of the first column?

Comment: @Starx:selection must always start from second row second cell only (not include header selection)user select only time if user select more than 12 cell i give alert  but in one cell selection cell length be 3.

Comment: I am unable to be clear about your concept.

Comment: see my fiddle by dragging i am selecting 2 cells.I have to make it one cell selction that is tr td:nth-child(2)

Comment: see my code i have make one cell selection Now what i want textbox value goes to next cell of selection where selection starts.if i make selection from 8:00AM 15 to 45 then textbox value goes to next cell of  8:00AM 15 and make rowspan '2' (tr td:nth-child(2)) ...

Comment: How i check contains text $cell.find('span').text(jQuery('#patientNames').val());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
jQuery('#update').click(function() {
    var cells=$('#tableAppointment tbody tr td:nth-child(3)');
    var i=0;
    var topcell=false;
    cells.each(function() {
        var $cell = $(this);

        if ($cell.hasClass('csstdhighlight')) {
            if(i==0){
                $cell.find('span').text(jQuery('#patientNames').val());
                topcell=$cell;
            }else{
               $cell.remove();
            }
            i++;
        }
    });
    if(topcell) topcell.attr('rowspan',i);
});​
```

Comment: jornare:u r going correct way but how to make rowspan cell should be colored wirh class csstdhighlight

Comment: can u make jsfiddle for one cell selection and above functionality on button click

Comment: How i check contains text $cell.find('span').text(jQuery('#patientNames').val());

Comment: :on double click of button $cell.remove(); rowspan lost